# D3 can't draw two brushes together

Tags: javascript, d3.js

so I am trying to make something where the user can drag and create two equal sized brushes in a line chart, the problem is that brush disappears after I try to draw the second one. I have tried to create separate attr and seperate brush call but still can't do it.
this is my code https://jsfiddle.net/f0gxs41t/

any help?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <svg width="960" height="400"></svg>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>
    line chart with drag and drop
  </title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./line_graph.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

js file :

```
var data=[1,5,2,7,4,7,8,9,5,3,6,8,2,3,5,9,8,5]

var svg=d3.select("svg")
var margin={top:100,bottom:50,left:100,right:0},
   width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
   height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
   g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var x_extent=d3.extent(data,function(d,i){return i})
var y_extent=d3.extent(data,function(d,i){return d})


x=d3.scale.linear()
.range([0,width])
.domain(x_extent)

y=d3.scale.linear()
.range([height,0])
.domain(y_extent)

var line=d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d,i){ return x(i)})
.y(function(d,i){return y(d)})

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left");

// g.append("g")
// .append("text")
// .attr("fill", "#000")
// .attr("transform","rotate(-90)")
// .attr("y",-35)
// .attr("dy","0.71em")
// .attr("text-anchor","end")
// .text("break something")

g.append("path")
.attr("class","line")
.datum(data)
.attr("d",line)

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + (height+margin.top) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+ ","+margin.top+")")
    .call(yAxis);

var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// if (brush.empty()!==true){
//
// }



var brushes = [];
var parent_brush=d3.svg.brush()
          .x(x)
          .on("brushend",brushed)

var brush1=d3.svg.brush()
          .x(x)
          .on("brushend",brushed)



function brushed(){
  if (parent_brush.empty()==true){
    console.log(parent_brush,"empty")
  }
  else {
    brush_width=parent_brush.extent()[1]-parent_brush.extent()[0]
        console.log(parent_brush,"not empty")
  }
}


svg.append("g")
.attr("class","parent")
.call(parent_brush)
.selectAll("rect")
.attr("x",margin.left)
.attr("y",margin.top)
.attr("height",height)
.style("fill","orange")
.style("fill-opacity",".2")


svg.append("g")
.attr("class","child")
.call(brush1)
.selectAll("rect")
.attr("x",margin.left)
.attr("y",margin.top)
.attr("height",height)
.style("fill","orange")
.style("fill-opacity",".2")
```

css file:

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.hover-line {
  stroke: #6F257F;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 3,3;
}
.area {
  fill: lightsteelblue;
}
.line{
  fill:none;
  stroke:brown;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-width:1.5
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
.brush {
  fill: grey;
  pointer-events: all;
  fill-opacity:0.3;
}

.resize  {
  fill: grey;
  pointer-events: all;
  fill-opacity:0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider using d3.js v4...

Child brush is created in the parent brush "end" event handler, where we also need to disable new parent brush selections.

```
var parent_brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [margin.left, margin.top],
    [margin.left + width, margin.top + height]
  ])
  .on("end", brushedParent);
var child_brush;

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "parent")
  .call(parent_brush);

function brushedParent() {
  // remove new brush selection capture area
  svg.select('.parent .overlay').remove();

  if (!child_brush) {
    child_brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([
        [margin.left, margin.top],
        [margin.left + width, margin.top + height]
      ])
      .on("end", brushedChild);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "child")
      .call(child_brush);
  }
}

function brushedChild() {
  // remove new brush selection capture area
  svg.select('.child .overlay').remove();

  child_selection = d3.brushSelection(svg.select('.child').node());

  var parent_selection = d3.brushSelection(svg.select('.parent').node());
  var parent_width = parent_selection[1] - parent_selection[0];
  var resized_child = [child_selection[0], child_selection[0] + parent_width];

  child_brush.on("end", null);
  child_brush.move(svg.select('.child'), resized_child);
}
```

Here is the working code snippet:

```js
var data = [1, 5, 2, 7, 4, 7, 8, 9, 5, 3, 6, 8, 2, 3, 5, 9, 8, 5]

var svg = d3.select("svg")
var margin = {
    top: 100,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 100,
    right: 0
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
  return i
})
var y_extent = d3.extent(data, function(d, i) {
  return d
})

x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(x_extent)

y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0])
  .domain(y_extent)

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x(i)
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return y(d)
  })

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

g.append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", line)

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (height + margin.top) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .call(yAxis);

var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var brushes = [];
var parent_brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [margin.left, margin.top],
    [margin.left + width, margin.top + height]
  ])
  .on("end", brushedParent);
var child_brush;

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "parent")
  .call(parent_brush);

function brushedParent() {
  // remove new brush selection capture area
  svg.select('.parent .overlay').remove();

  if (!child_brush) {
    child_brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([
        [margin.left, margin.top],
        [margin.left + width, margin.top + height]
      ])
      .on("end", brushedChild);

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "child")
      .call(child_brush);
  }
}

function brushedChild() {
  // remove new brush selection capture area
  svg.select('.child .overlay').remove();

  child_selection = d3.brushSelection(svg.select('.child').node());

  var parent_selection = d3.brushSelection(svg.select('.parent').node());
  var parent_width = parent_selection[1] - parent_selection[0];
  var resized_child = [child_selection[0], child_selection[0] + parent_width];

  child_brush.on("end", null);
  child_brush.move(svg.select('.child'), resized_child);
}
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 1;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.hover-line {
  stroke: #6F257F;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 3, 3;
}

.area {
  fill: lightsteelblue;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: brown;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 1.5
}

.focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}

.brush {
  fill: grey;
  pointer-events: all;
  fill-opacity: 0.3;
}

.resize {
  fill: grey;
  pointer-events: all;
  fill-opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="960" height="400"></svg>
```

Comment: @TaranjeetSingh you're welcome... but before you unbind the "end" event listener, check if there is some selection created, because this way a simple click on the chart area unbinds it :)

Comment: what is the alternative for d3.brushSelection in v3?

Comment: @TaranjeetSingh, not sure, you might need to get those dimensions manually from '.brush .selection' [d3-3.x-api-reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/8a6827cee879765cf663fdd751187546688e9941/SVG-Controls.md)